# jquery custom scrollbar jumping to starting point when a button is clicked for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, mcustomscrollbar

I am using jQuery [custom scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) to display bunch of blocks with buttons. those buttons have alert script to show a msg when each button is clicked. Initially visible buttons are working fine as below

[image]

but after a scroll the next buttons[image 2]
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efvgw.png)

are not showing the alert instead of it skipping the scroller layout to starting like below 
[image]

Please help me on this to short out this problem.below i added the entire html content **run the code snippet with full page**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <title>jQuery custom scrollbar demo</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
 <!-- stylesheet for demo and examples -->
 <style>
  body{ background:#eee; font-family:arial, sans-serif; font-size:1em; line-height:1.6em; }
  h1{ margin:40px 0; }
  h1 small{ font-size:.5em; }
  hr{ border-top:0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
  a{ color:#0d75ca; }
  a:hover{ text-decoration:none; }
  header, #demo, footer{ width:70%; margin:0 auto; }
  footer p > a{ margin-right:20px; }
 </style>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

 <!-- custom scrollbar stylesheet -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">

 <style>
  /* mobile first */
  #content-1{
   width: 260px;
   height: 400px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: #fdfdfd;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 20px 0;
  }
  #content-1 ul{
   width: 230px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  #content-1 li{
   width: 200px;
   height: 120px;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   background: #dbf3f7;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){
   #content-1{
    width: 80%;
    height: 170px;
   }
   #content-1 ul{ width: auto; }
   #content-1 li{ float: left; }
  }
 </style>

</head>

<body>
 <header>
  <h1>custom scroller test</h1>
 </header>

 <div id="demo">
  <section id="examples">

   <!-- content -->
   <div id="content-1">
    <ul>
     <li>First</li>
     <li>Second</li>
     <li>Third</li>
     <li>Fourth</li>
     <li><button type="button" name="button" onclick="mycall()">call</button></li>
     <li>Sixth</li>
     <li>Seventh</li>
     <li><button type="button" name="button" onclick="mycall()">call</button></li>
     <li>Eigth</li>
     <li>Ninth</li>
     <li><button type="button" name="button" onclick="mycall()">call</button></li>
     <li>Eleventh</li>
     <li>Twelfth</li>
     <li>Thirteenth</li>
     <li>Last</li>
    </ul>
   </div>

  </section>
 </div>

 <footer>

 </footer>

 <!-- Google CDN jQuery with fallback to local -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/minified/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

 <!-- custom scrollbar plugin (latest version) via Github with fallback to local -->
 <script src="http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.mCustomScrollbar || document.write('<script src="../jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

 <script>
  (function($){

   $(window).load(function(){

    $("#content-1").mCustomScrollbar({
     theme:"inset-2-dark",
     axis:"x",
     advanced:{autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true},

     /* change mouse-wheel axis on-the-fly */
     callbacks:{
      onOverflowY:function(){
       var opt=$(this).data("mCS").opt;
       if(opt.mouseWheel.axis!=="y") opt.mouseWheel.axis="y";
      },
      onOverflowX:function(){
       var opt=$(this).data("mCS").opt;
       if(opt.mouseWheel.axis!=="x") opt.mouseWheel.axis="x";
      },
     }
    });

   });

  })(jQuery);
 </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function mycall(){
      alert("test");
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: folks please tell me why you people not answering for this question ..is anything wrong i did here..please let me know if any